# Where to IEnumerable that contains a list of objects

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, where-clause, ienumerable

I new to EntityFrameworkCore and Asp.Net Core and I have the following problem.
I have 2 tables, Diplomas and Teachers and I am trying to select the diplomas that have as TeacherName the given one. I use Join() in order to inner join the 2 tables but I keep receiving an error. How can I achieve this, or is there some other way to do it ?
Using Asp.Net Core 5.0 and EntityFrameworkCore 5.0

**Models**

```cs
public class Diploma
{
    public Diploma(){
        this.Status = "Pending";
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]     
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Teachers")]
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Student Name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "FilePath")]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "TeacherName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DiplomaId { get; set; }
    public Diploma Diploma { get; set; }
}
```

**SQlRepository**

```cs
public IEnumerable<Diploma> GetAllDiplomasForTeachers(string username)
{
    Teacher t = new Teacher();
    t.Name = username;            

    var query = context.Diplomas.Join(
        context.Teachers,
        diploma => diploma.Id,
        teacher => teacher.DiplomaId,
        (diploma, teacher) => new Diploma
        {
            Id = diploma.Id,
            Title = diploma.Title,
            Description = diploma.Description,
            StudentName = diploma.StudentName,
            Teachers = context.Teachers.ToList<Teacher>(),
            Status = diploma.Status,
            FilePath = diploma.FilePath
        }
        ).Where(a => a.Teachers.Contains(t)); //This line produces[enter image description here][1] the following error
    return query;
}
```

[image]

**Controller**

```cs
public ViewResult ShowDiplomas()
{
    var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);            
    var diploma = _diplomaRepository.GetAllDiplomasForTeachers(userName);                                    
    if (diploma == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"No diploma is created yet";                
    }
    return View(diploma);
}
```

**Database Tables**

```
Teachers
TeacherId,Name,DiplomaId

Diplomas
Id,Title,Description,StudentName,Status,FilePath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is much simpler that you have tried to create. Usually it is not needed to create JOINs if you have properly defined navigation properties.

```cs
public IEnumerable<Diploma> GetAllDiplomasForTeachers(string username)
{
    var query = context.Diplomas
        .Include(d => d.Teachers)
        .Where(d => d.Teachers.Any(t => t.Name == userName));
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am quite new in asp.net core so simple things seem difficult !!